# directive function calling multiple times in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created directive in anguular js to resize image in angularjs. 
Here is the code of directive :

```
app.directive('resize1', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            params: '&',
            path: '=',
            siteurl: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.resizeImage = function() {
                var size = 0;
                var width = angular.element($window).width();
                src = $(element).attr('src');

                if (src != null || src != '') {
                    var url = parse_url(src).query;
                    var path = parse_url(src).path;

                    var str = url.split('&');
                    var link = '?';
                    $.each(str, function(index, value) {
                        pair = value.split('=');
                        if (pair[0] != 'h' && pair[0] != 'w') {

                            link = link + value + '&';
                        }
                    });

                    if (width >= 960) {
                        size = $scope.$eval($scope.params).gt960;
                        newWidth = size.w;
                        newHeight = size.h;

                    } else if (width < 960 && width >= 480) {
                        size = $scope.$eval($scope.params).bt480960;
                        newWidth = size.w;
                        newHeight = size.h;
                    } else {
                        size = $scope.$eval($scope.params).lt480;
                        newWidth = size.w;
                        newHeight = size.h;
                    }
                    link = link + 'h=' + newHeight + '&w=' + newWidth;
                    $(element).attr('src', path +  link);
                    $(element).attr('ng-src', path +  link);
                    $(element).closest('div.spinner').css({
                        'height' : newHeight,
                        'width' : newWidth,
                        'margin' : '0px auto'
                    });
                }
            };

            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                $scope.resizeImage();
            });

            $scope.$watch('path', function (){
                //alert('df');
                $scope.resizeImage();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and my html is :

```
<div class="list-view" ng-hide="productDetail == null">
    <div class="list-view-img">
        <div class="spinner">
            <img resize1
                ng-src="{{siteurl}}thumbnails/index?file={{path}}&h=200&w=200"
                params="{lt480: {h: 300,w: 300}, bt480960: {h: 450,w: 450}, gt960: {h: 940,w: 940}}"
                path="paths.products.primary_image + productDetail.primary_image"
                siteurl="siteUrl"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is its working fine but directive function is called 3 times..
Can anybody tell me what can be wrong ? why it is called thrice though i have called it once ?

Comment: What is being executed 3 times? If it's the directive creation, then you are adding the file where it gets declard 3 times. If you're talking about the linking function of the directive, then you probably have a `ng-repeat` or you use the same directive 3 times, wont you? Post more context for the HTML.

Comment: no i m not using ng-repeat.. and m talking about linking function.. it is getting called 3 times.. Even I have declared directive once only in whole project.

Comment: Would you post the context of this `<div>` up to the HTML? Is there a `ng-view`, `ng-switch`? If HTML is too big, which directives you use following the `<div>` ancestors?

Comment: Are you sure it is link function getting called?  Or is it `resizeImage`?